# Use 'if' statement in ModelBuilder to stop model

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, error-000539

I would like to use an `if-else` statement in my model (along the lines of [this Esri blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/06/modelbuilderifthenelse1/)). My model works fine (several intersects, dissolves, calculating fields, joins). However, I would like to add a check after the first process runs, which is an `Intersect`. If the output has 0 rows (using `Get Count`), the model should stop, else continue. Using the following code in the `Calculate Value` code code block

```
def countRows(rowcount):
    import arcpy
    if %rowcount% == 0:
        return false
    else:
        return true
```

and expression

```
countRows(%rowcount%)
```

The model runs and generates a warning

```
The process did no execute because the precondition is false.
```

It then just carries on running the other processes, all which generate the warning

```
All the inputs are not current.
```

To summarise: The input is intersected, and the rows in the output are counted. If the number of rows is 0, return false and stop. If true, carry on processing. The `Calculate Value` tool is set as a precondition before all the other processes can run. I've looked at the `Stop-Continue` tool as well, but I'm not sure how (if?) I should be using it in this instance.

**edit** Ran the model on an input that I knew would generate some rows after the intersect, when the `Calculate Value` ran and returned `true`, the model stopped with the error

```
Error 000539: Error running expression: countRows(3546) <type 'exceptions.NameError'>:
global name 'true' is not defined. Failed to execute (Calculate Value).
```

Comment: Use proper case for True/False, that should probably fix it :)

Comment: Actually use lower-case, quoted values (strings), this is apparently what the model expects for preconditions.

Comment: @blah238 that worked! Now the other branch of my model is failing, but I think that's because I got overexcited with my preconditions, I'll relax some of them now. Could you please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue as the original question. Currently my true/false values in the calculate value tool are all-caps and when I change them to lower case and hit OK, they revert back to all caps. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: I was able to change the true/false values to lower case but still getting "The process did no execute because the precondition is false." and "All the inputs are not current." errors.  The second message comes on the export to cad tool.

Comment: @Steve Regarding your first issue, that normally happens when the model gets "tired" i.e. you have been fiddling with it for a while. I know that's not really an explanation but in my experience that is what happens to models. For best results you will need to open a new model and set it up again like your old one. Also, the `Get Count` tool output can be used as true/false, without needing to write the conditional test.

Comment: Arabella, thank you for the response.  I'm not sure how to use get count to do the condition but I used the calculate value tool to do it.

Comment: @Steve set the output of `Get Count` as the precondition to whichever tool you are wanting to get a true/false condition for.

Comment: Thanks Arabella, good to know.  I'll try this method going forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use lower-case, quoted values (strings), this is apparently what the model expects for preconditions.

e.g. `return "true"` or `return "false"`

Answer (score 0):

If your using 10 or above simply use the GET COUNT function in ModelBuilder and use rowCount as a precondition for your intersection.

Answer (score 0):

This was both handy and detailed:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/06/modelbuilderifthenelse1/